# Use of the expression "for some element $x$ $\in$ a subgroup $H$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

This is a question asking for clarification in use of the terms such as "for some element..." and "let $x$ be an arbitrary element in a set...." in abstract algebra. Let's say I have a group $M$ and it has two subgroups $A$ and $B$. Now also, let's say that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are two elements in $M$ and they are related by a relation $R$ iff $am_1b$ = $m_2$ for some element $a$ $\in$ $A$ and $b$ $\in$ $B$. So, my confusion arose in proving symmetry. 
I have $am_1b$ = $m_2$. So does it mean, I have to show that $am_2b$ = $m_1$ for the same $a$ and $b$? Cause what I am thinking is that just by applying inverses of $a$ and $b$ , I will get $m_1$ = $a^{-1}m_2b^{-1}$, and since $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $M$, the inverses of $a$ and $b$ will exist in $A$ and $B$ respectively. So, is the symmetry property verified?

Comment: In the future, for exponents that are more than one character long, you can enclose the exponent in braces like `{}`. That is, in this case, `a^{-1}` produces $a^{-1}$, as opposed to $a^-1$ with no braces.

Comment: Thank you @Clayton. I was confused about that.

Comment: No, it does not mean that you have to show that $am_2b=m_1$ for the same $a$ and $b$. It says for **some** $a$ and $b$, not for the **same** $a$ and $b$. So you are done as you say.

Comment: Thank you @DietrichBurde.